# Using Realm for Xamarin Forms with a preexisting SQL database?

Tags: sql, mobile, xamarin.forms, realm

We have a preexisting SQL database that holds our data and will be updated from time to time. I've just stumbled across Realm and don't quite understand how it works at the moment.

From the examples I've seen it looks as if Realm creates the database locally on the mobile device (please correct me if I'm wrong). This is not what we want. We want our data to live on some server and then pull that into the application.

Can this be done purely with Realm? Or should we somehow pull from the SQL server? What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Realm is a local db on the device.  If your db lives on the server, you will need to write a webservice layer to expose it to the device.  You may also want to use Realm or SQLite for a local copy of your data on the device, but that depends on your app's requirements.

Comment: @Jason is right, Realm only runs on the device.